# Convert NSManagedObjects into structs in a "generic" way (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a `CoreDataStore` class which has two generic placeholders and can be used for each entity type in the model. The idea is that it fetches an `NSManagedObject` subclass (based on one of the generic types) from the store, converts it into the appropriate object (based on the other generic type) and returns that object.

The **purpose** of this behaviour is so I'm keeping the Core Data aspects encapsulated and avoiding passing `NSManagedObject` instances all around the app.

**Example potential usage**

This is purely how the usage *might* look to further demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

```
let personStore = CoreDataStore<ManagedPerson, Person>()
let personData = personStore.fetchSomeObject() // personData is a value type Person
```

I have the following code, separated over several files but shown here in a modified fashion for simplicity.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

// MARK: - Core Data protocol and managed object

protocol ManagedObjectProtocol { }

class ManagedPerson: NSManagedObject, ManagedObjectProtocol {
    var title: String?
}

class ManagedDepartment: NSManagedObject, ManagedObjectProtocol {
    var name: String?
}

// MARK: - Simple struct representations

protocol DataProtocol {
    typealias ManagedObjectType: ManagedObjectProtocol
    init(managedObject: ManagedObjectType)
}

struct Person {
    var title: String?
}

struct Department {
    var name: String?
}

extension Person: DataProtocol {
    typealias ManagedObjectType = ManagedPerson
    init(managedObject: ManagedPerson) {
        self.title = managedObject.title
    }
}

extension Department: DataProtocol {
    typealias ManagedObjectType = ManagedDepartment
    init(managedObject: ManagedDepartment) {
        self.name = managedObject.name
    }
}

class CoreDataStore<ManagedObject: ManagedObjectProtocol, DataObject: DataProtocol> {

    func fetchSomeObject() -> DataObject {
        var managedObject: ManagedObject // fetch an NSManagedObject

        // Error here
        return DataObject(managedObject: managedObject)
    }

}
```

The error I am receiving is when I try to initialise the struct in `fetchSomeObject`:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'DataObject' with an argument list of type '(managedObject: ManagedObject)'

Obviously the compiler can't figure out that the `DataObject` (which is restricted to types conforming to `DataProtocol`) can be initialised with a `ManagedObject` (which is restricted to types conforming to `ManagedObjectProtocol`) despite it being declared as such in `DataProtocol`.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality? Additionally is this a reasonable approach or am I completely off the wall with this?

### Update

After a bit of digging it seems that [Swift generics are invariant](http://www.functionalgibberish.com/blog/2015/7/24/swifts-2-biggest-missing-features) which I believe is causing what I'm running into.

Comment: Well, very simply, neither extension actually follows your `DataProtocol`, which requires an `init(managedObject: ManagedObjectProtocol)` - you can't get round that by providing an init using some random subclass - you've got to conform to the actual protocol definition.

Comment: To fulfil the protocol contract you've got to provide the exact `init` you said you were going to, not a different one. The best I can see is if you replace your two concrete `init`s with the protocol's and test inside for class conformance (though you'll probably need to make it failable to do that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think your `CoreDataStore` again, for example, `CoreDataStore<ManagedPerson, Department>` doesn't make any sense. Why not? Because the `Department` is a `DataProtocol` without problem, but its corresponding typealias  `ManagedObjectType` is not `ManagedPerson`.

The reason why your code won't compile is just the same. Here `return DataObject(managedObject: managedObject)` you can't initialize an `DataObject` from an armbitary `ManagedObject`, only a `DataObject.ManagedObjectType` is acceptable.

So what you need is a type constraint, add this where clause, your code should work:

```
class CoreDataStore<ManagedObject: ManagedObjectProtocol, DataObject: DataProtocol
    where DataObject.ManagedObjectType == ManagedObject>
```

Comment: `class CoreDataStore<ManagedObject: ManagedObjectProtocol, DataObject: DataProtocol> where DataObject.ManagedObjectType == ManagedObject`